# How to get the last character of string after a space in sql db2

Tags: sql, db2

Supposed that i have these  values

| Value |
| --- |
| MPP ref |
| MPP ref MPP-V_ACC0000002-02 B |
| MPP ref X |
| MPP ref MPP-V_ACC0000001-01 E |

I'm trying to get the last character  of a string just after a space

Output should be :

| Substr |
| --- |
|  |
| B |
| X |
| E |

My query  :

```
select   RIGHT(trim(value  ), 1) as Substr   from  MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a combination of the `RIGHT` and `LEFT` functions to achieve this. The case expression first extracts the 2 most right values before checking if the left most value is a space to determine strings ending with a space before the last character. If this criteria is met, it returns this character using the right function otherwise null.

```sql
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN LEFT(RIGHT(value,2),1)=' ' THEN RIGHT(value,1)
        ELSE NULL
    END as Substr
FROM
    MyTable
```

[Working Demo DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=af9150cdde0f97cefa8c815527698b00)

Let me know if this works for you